# options not loading into cart

Tags: php, magento

OK, so I have a module that works. In the module, I add multiple products with some options like this:

```
public function indexAction() { 
    $prod_count = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prod_count');
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init(); 
    for($i = 1; $i <= $prod_count ;$i++){
        $prod_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('prod_'.$i.'_id');
        $prod_count = $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_'.$i.'_count');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prod_id);
        $options = array('options' => NULL);
        for($u = 1; $u <= $prod_count; $u++){
            $op_id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('option_id_'.$u.'_'.$i);
            $op_type_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('option_type_id_'.$u.'_'.$i);
            $options['options'][] = array( $op_id => $op_type_id);
        }
        $copy = array();
        for($r = 0; $r < count($options['options']); $r++){
            array_push($copy,$options['options'][$r]);
            var_dump($copy);
        }
        echo $prod_id.'<br><br>';try {  
        $params = array(
                    'product' => $prod_id, // This would be $product->getId()
                    'qty' => 1,
                    'options' => $copy
                ); 
        $request = new Varien_Object();
        $request->setData($params);
        $cart->addProduct($product, $request); 
        Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $cart->save();  
        }catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
        }
    }       
    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        exit('1'); 
    } 
    $session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); 
}
```

But when I execute this on my site, it only adds the product with no options to the store, and yes, I made sure to check if I'm even getting options. Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should check data of `$copy` variable. The parameters should be in format:

```
Array
(
    [product] => 171     // product id
    [options] => Array
        (
            [4] => 1111  // <option_id> => <selected value>
            [3] => 7     // <option_id> => <selected value>
        )

    [qty] => 1
)
```

Also, you don't need

```
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($params);
```

just pass `$params` like this:

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
```

Comment: shit, your right. I swear I spent time making sure $copy was in the right format. Thanks!